# systemd “status=203/EXEC”,запуская телеграм бота на сервер

Tags: python, ubuntu, service, putty, systemd

Столкнулся с проблемой активации телеграм бота на сервере.Возникает ошибка status=203/EXEC.Бота пробую активировать при помощи systemd.Все директории указаны верно,всё необходимое установлено на сервер.Атрибуты у всех файлов 777.Думаю,что проблема из-за некорректного написания Execstart.Как можно исправить?Ниже приведу код файла bot.service.

```
`#!/bin/bash
 [Unit]
 Description=Cham4V
 After=syslog.target
 After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/bin/bot
ExecStart="/usr/local/bin/python3.8  /usr/local/bin/bot/shka.py"
RestartSec=10
Restart=always`

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target`
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 203 код ошибки из за неверного пути к некому  файлу, требуемому процессу для работы.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич,все пути к директориям указаны верно.

Comment: путь может быть не верным где угодно, в том числе в зависимостях и в открываемых процессом файлах. А еще у службы может не быть доступа к директории с заданными ей правами, это тоже проверьте.